# Google drive API access for aplication testing

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am working on an application which uses Google Oauth2 token and the purpose of application is to download specific file from logged user's Google Drive. I am wondering if there is any chance to test that before going to production environment. I've enabled Google Drive API in Google Cloud Platform created Oauth 2.0 Client ID.

[image]

[image]

I've got web application created using Java and Spring and authorisation works good. I do receive Oauth 2.0 token from Google Sign In but when I add a scope for Google drive which is the same one added in GCP I do receive following error:

[image]

Below is spring security google scope:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

And the spring security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/styles/**", "/webjars/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/goodbye");
    }
}
```

I found some information that if the registered application in GCP has sensitive scope it should goes through validation process but I want to test it first before going to production that's why I've left that in Testing Oauth consent and added testing user but it doesn't work.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Reproducible example:

1. Register app in GCP.
2. Enable Google Drive API and generate Oauth2 credential.
3. Add auth/drive.readonly scope.
4. Set consent status to testing and add testing user.
5. Create Spring Boot app with Spring Security.
6. Add scope:

   spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
7. Run app and authenticate with Google Sign in.

Comment: When/where exactly are you getting this error? Also, can you provide the code corresponding to the authorization and the request?

Comment: Error appears after Google sign in. There is no specific code for Google authorisation. Just a spring security http chain.

Comment: Not a solution but a step to better understand your problem: if you try the call from the "Try this API" (eg https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) you can see the request made in the Network tab of the Chrome DevTools. From there take the "authorization" header, if it works that is a valid access_token. You can use that to send a request with your code and check if it works. If it does, your problem is in the credential retrieval, not in the API call.

Comment: @NicolòGasparini I didn't try to call drive api yet. The error which is thrown comes from Google Sign in page

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Iamblichus reproducible example added